# Getting Chinese data as UTF8 from web service

Tags: ios, web-services, utf-8

I am trying to access a url which is returning some data which has Chinese characters. It returns following response in browser:

> {"news":"新聞發佈"}

But when I am trying to read it in my Objective C code I am getting nil in nsdata. Following is my Objective C code:

```
NSString *final_url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx/iph1/NewsAction.do?service=NEWSNOTIF&lang=2&uid=xxxxxxx"];

final_url = [final_url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:final_url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *strResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *objectData = [strResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                       error:&error];
NSLog(@"json %@",json);
```

### Edit

For testing server guy is sending following data:

```
String testJson ="&#26032;&#32862;&#30332;&#20296;";
```

Comment: Clarify which value is `nil` - is it `data`, `strResponse`, `objectData`, or `json`?

Comment: Your code also assumes the text from the web service is encoded in UTF-8. Are you sure that's actually true?

Comment: Hi maddy, I have talked with the guy who is working on web service and he says he is sending UTF-8, I am getting data as nil.

Comment: Log `error` when `data` is nil.

Comment: NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]; data here has only nil, no error

Comment: What did you get when you logged `error`?

Answer (score 0):

I there is no error. And data is nil. Then the response form the server itself is not being received. First try by asking the server to send normal string. I think the reason data is nil is not to do with the string encoding here. I suspect the response itself isn't received.